# which regression is appropriate for numeric non-continuous outcome

Tags: regression

I have an outcome which is a total score from questionnaire. It ranges between 0 and 100 in steps of 2. I have small sample size of 40. I want to look at the effect of hearing loss (yes/no) on this total score. I am wondering whether a linear regression is appropriate for this type of outcome? I need to mention that I adjust for age and gender in the regression.

Comment: I don't think you have enough data to do anything clever here. It sounds like a case where you could just test the difference of the means for the two groups.

Comment: Nothing about your characterizations distinguishes this problem from any other standard regression problem nor precludes applying standard techniques.  As always, you need to follow the usual approaches of checking whether your data exhibit evidence that the assumptions required for applying regression (of any sort) and relying on its results do hold.  If you would like a more specific answer, then please edit your post to include information that would enable us to check those assumptions, such as appropriate graphical and summary descriptions of your data.

Comment: @ whuber do you mean that I can do linear regression and then check the assumptions of linear regression such as normality of residuals, ...? I have not started the analysis yet, so I cannot provide description of data yet, sorry.

Comment: Linear regression should be fine here. Of course, you still have to check the assumptions.